# FCM rest request response is 200, but message does not show in FCM console neither in the app

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a firebase app, integrating with IOS devices. 
When I send messages from FCM console it works and the device gets the notification. 
When I try from a Rest call, I received the response that was ok, but the messages do not appear in FCM console either in the app.

My request is like this:

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-sample-app/messages:send
{
  "message":{
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message",
      },
    "token" : "donEbJ2q5oU:APA91bFFo1l6aw5OVu515Pulel4J1t6dL-XXXXX",
   }
}

Response:
{
    "name": "projects/my-sample-app/messages/8948907274494952894"
}
```

I don't have any error in the call, but I can not see the message anywhere.

What I'm missing here?